# Can you measure a text string size without a ICanvas instance in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, graphics, maui

I am able to measure a text string size in the Draw method call of a IDrawable object, using the ICanvas.GetStringSize method.

Now, what if I need to measure a text string before the drawing happens ? In my use case for example, the bounding box of the drawable object ([second parameter in the Draw method call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.graphics.idrawable.draw?view=net-maui-7.0)) is to be set by the parent ContentView given a font size, by computing the maximum size which could be taken by a text string in this font size. This is illustrated with the following pseudo-code:

```
private void OnFontSizeChanged(int fontSize)
{
    // The string possible values are integers in the [1-9999] range
    var maxTextSize = GetStringSize("9999", fontSize);
    
    // Now we know the font size, we can set the GraphicsView object size once
    // according to the maximum width/height that can be taken by the child drawing.
    HeightRequest = maxTextSize.Height * 1.2f;
    WidthRequest = maxTextSize.Width * 1.2f;
}
```

Is there a way to measure the text size without using ICanvas in the scenario I described ? Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: The problem here is that the font size and the string itself are not enough to calculate the text size. It depends also on the font you use, the text style (bold, italic...) and probably other settings I'm forgetting now. All that stuff is contained in the instance of `ICanvas` and that's because `GetStringSize` is a method of `ICanvas`. What you could try to do is to update the `ContentView` size after drawing your text, when you can retrieve the actual text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody dealing with a similar problematic, here is what I did based on the solution suggested by IV.

Whenever the SizeChanged event of the GraphicsView object is raised, I handle it by setting a boolean property from the underlying IDrawable object so when its Draw method gets called the next time, it will do a measurement of the content that is to get drawn, and then call RequiredSizeComputed event handler so the GraphicsView knows the size has been computed.

Now that the size has been computed, the GraphicsView calls Invalidate so the Draw method is called again, but now with knowledge of the appropriate size of the different graphical elements.

GraphicsView code:

```
public ValueOutOfTotal()
{
    Drawable = ValueOutOfTotalDrawable = new ValueOutOfTotalDrawable();
    SizeChanged += ValueOutOfTotal_SizeChanged;
    ValueOutOfTotalDrawable.RequiredSizeComputed += ValueOutOfTotalDrawable_RequiredSizeComputed;
}

private void ValueOutOfTotalDrawable_RequiredSizeComputed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is SizeComputedEventArgs sizeComputedEventArgs)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private void ValueOutOfTotal_SizeChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValueOutOfTotalDrawable.MustComputeRequiredSize = true;
}
```

IDrawable code: (the ComputeRequiredSize method is of course to be implemented with information about whatever you are about to draw)

```
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        if (MustComputeRequiredSize)
        {
            _sizeInfo = ComputeRequiredSize(canvas, dirtyRect);
            MustComputeRequiredSize = false;
            RequiredSizeComputed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            Draw(canvas, dirtyRect, ValueColor, TotalColor, SeparatorColor, TitleColor, ValueFontSize, TotalFontSize, TitleFontSize, Value, Total, Title, _sizeInfo);
        }
    }
```

And if you can find the largest possible font using IV method adjusted for this context:

```
private static float ComputeMaxFontSize(string title, ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
    float minFontSize = 1;
    float maxFontSize = 200;
    double tolerance = 0.1;
    double targetHeight = dirtyRect.Height * 0.9;
    double targetWidth = dirtyRect.Width * 0.8;

    while (minFontSize < maxFontSize)
    {
        float midFontSize = (minFontSize + maxFontSize) / 2;
        Size drawingSize = ComputeRequiredSize(canvas, title, midFontSize);

        bool isHeightWithinTolerance = Math.Abs(drawingSize.Height - targetHeight) <= targetHeight * tolerance;
        bool isWidthWithinLabel = drawingSize.Width <= targetWidth;

        if (isHeightWithinTolerance && isWidthWithinLabel)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (drawingSize.Height > targetHeight || drawingSize.Width > targetWidth)
        {
            maxFontSize = midFontSize - 0.1f;
        }
        else
        {
            minFontSize = midFontSize + 0.1f;
        }
    }

    return (minFontSize + maxFontSize) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `Label.Measure` in one of my projects in an attempt to do some responsive font scaling. You might be able to adapt it for your purposes. In my case, the basic idea was to do a binary search based on the measured size.

Based on some preliminary experiments, if one wanted to use a dummy label for measurement purposes it seems that the label *does* need to be in the visual tree somewhere but *doesn't* need to be visible.

---

[image: screenshot]

---

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();

    private void AnySizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is Label label)
        {
            double minFontSize = 1;
            double maxFontSize = 100;
            double tolerance = 0.1;
            double targetHeight = label.Height * 0.9;
            double targetWidth = label.Width * 0.8; 

            while (minFontSize < maxFontSize)
            {
                double midFontSize = (minFontSize + maxFontSize) / 2;
                label.FontSize = midFontSize;
                Size textSize = label.Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity).Request;
                bool isHeightWithinTolerance = Math.Abs(textSize.Height - targetHeight) <= targetHeight * tolerance;
                bool isWidthWithinLabel = textSize.Width <= targetWidth;

                if (isHeightWithinTolerance && isWidthWithinLabel)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (textSize.Height > targetHeight || textSize.Width > targetWidth)
                {
                    maxFontSize = midFontSize - 0.1;
                }
                else
                {
                    minFontSize = midFontSize + 0.1; 
                }
            }
            label.FontSize = (minFontSize + maxFontSize) / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml, handle the SizeChanged event.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicSizingProto"
             x:Class="DynamicSizingProto.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="*,*,2*,3*,4*,*">
        <Label
            Text="Text Placeholder"
            SizeChanged="AnySizeChanged"
            Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label
            Text="Text Placeholder"
            SizeChanged="AnySizeChanged"
            Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Label
            Text="Text Placeholder"
            SizeChanged="AnySizeChanged"
            Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Label
            Text="Text Placeholder"
            SizeChanged="AnySizeChanged"
            Grid.Row="4"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I would probably try and bake it into a custom extended `LabelEx` but this is the basic idea.

---

**iPad**

[image: test on iOS]

Comment: Thanks a lot I really like your solution and I think I will use this mechanism a lot in my apps. I have adjusted it to the context of a GraphicsView object so I have added another answer with those info.